# Looking for an aphorism/verse for "If you ask for less, you are more likely to receive it" (or the double inverse)

Tags: quotes, aphorism

Looking for an aphorism/verse for the sentiment...

> If you ask for less, you are more likely to receive it

...in the context of luck or prayers being answered.

Comment: You can't win if you don't play.

Comment: I think that what you've given is the aphorism.

Comment: Not an "aphorism", but it looks relevant to me: [***Foot-in-the-door**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot-in-the-door_technique) (FITD) technique is a compliance tactic that aims at getting a person to agree to a large request **by having them agree to a modest request first.***

Comment: Just make up your own—something like "A modest wish is sooner granted."

Comment: Granted that the context is not exactly the same (petition, versus claim), but it is worth at least noting what Jerome K. Jerome said: "In this world it is necessary to adopt the principle pursued by the plaintiff in an action for damages, and to demand ten times more than you are ready to accept. If you can feel satisfied with a hundred, begin by insisting on a thousand; if you start by suggesting a hundred you will only get ten."